# VBA conversion to Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-sheets

How can I reference specific cells in Google script to loop, and to return values to specific cells, like the example shown below in VBA.

**How would this be written in Google script?**

```
For j = 1 To 20 Step 2

For i = 1 To 20

g = Worksheets("Notes").Cells(i + 15, j + 2).Value

h = Worksheets("Notes").Cells(4, j + 2).Value

l = Worksheets("Notes").Cells(5, j + 2).Value

If Worksheets("Notes").Cells(i + 15, j + 2).Value <> "" Then
```

etc.

Answer (score 3):

You may use simple for loops in javascript to loop through the cells

```
//get the sheet object
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Notes');

for(j=0; j<=20; j++){
for(i=0; i<=20; i++){
g = sheet.getRange(i + 15, j + 2).getValue();
//...
//...
//and so on
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is an example:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Notes');
var lastrow=sheet.getLastRow();
var lastcolumn=sheet.getLastColumn();

//In Google Script you should specify the range you want I/O from
var range=sheet.getRange(1,1,lastcolumn,lastrow);

//Return 2D Array for all range Values
var all = range.getValues();

for(var j=0; j<=20; j++){
for(var i=0; i<=20; i++){

//Return each value
var all = range.getCell(i + 15, j + 2).getValue();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Better way is not to call getCell each time as you have already got the data.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Notes');
var lastrow=sheet.getLastRow();
var lastcolumn=sheet.getLastColumn();

//In Google Script you should specify the range you want I/O from
var range=sheet.getRange(1,1,lastcolumn,lastrow);

//Return 2D Array for all range Values
var values = range.getValues(); //2D array of row and column values

for(var r=0; r < values.length; r++){
  for(var c=0; c < values[r].length; c++) { 

  //Return each value
  var value = value[r][c]; //row, column

  }
}
```